# 45x45 Word Search

Tags: word-search, science

You'll need to be a serious fan of these puzzles to find over 300 of the things hidden in this jumble. There are no clues as this is test of knowledge as well as determination. Once you get started it's easy enough to find a list of what you are searching for.

Hint:

> When all the parts are spread before you on the table you will know each by number.

[image]

If you would like an alternative grid with the correct spelling of Aluminium and copyable text:

[image]

i1u105muinehtuRCm8S7muidanaVmuiboiN3N
al7mPbs5KrmuillahT80yDnegyxO0L711Bae6
NeTum31u1B57r112mMyBO5m352019muoC89nd
rkmiu6mur1iu313utro85muinatiTzut3T6iG
Bcuminu6Rofsn3iHur9mCuimuidibuRieFld8
Siidpoi55lhimmocomTumigm69m64Fm6dtNo4
mNnaotd3uTTplurnBumiudrgu44u7u2bTniI5
umeCrpoS2m1osetkmiuviioMSienitatsAIu4
iulHuyh2puH1MoHhutnocrb1n1smLdP921Umm
niedErRBmi391ghIidirnIa0e4yobso193SuN
ocSlAKRhurnoneXPnatee2e3gdnDrLuS9inib
timomuinietsniEmitalr7SZomo40p8Ul5enN
uruG6eF4nnR7OlmumslFwA8erPgmm2siEetfd
leim103mot26AumnumPPassStyruuTcyrnsaF
Pmru3mOuli57imuelrCFLaH2inAiio79DigHm
pAtinusioe2cSuidAaRar523NomnnM406rndu
uenhoi9rPMi4nibb0DgPlP611muei3o16ouMi
Unutbc5uCnu1orry2lmm1i391iigtU58muTen
HinirlCCrRP1rael68upm1fB0trtcmmLulSnu
fmULaarem2hCIBToaiimuM3o1nonAuumiFAit
Io1sCCpmu9nealCMtGmui23UrAhe4iiubr8rp
mr0mDo1uiesenagnaMsiduLu0nTo0nlire3oe
uB6uC1Wiln801iemmmOtrCGo5miR1aetevmlN
i36i7stleo10MpuNuumeoeu8HuvuVrbptluh4
n77r0Cllkd21nigmiiunfsm90i2umUoetiiC2
oLma19ayra8ubAmLnhihrEuC7vA4SmNsYSs94
crum91breRnr57uvitdceSiUae45iuPn85e5L
rmia00oeBUE935imtenehmmuileH1idu1mnr8
iumS10CBpN4817tucmaTturtheXcmtmn7ugeR
ZiyJmuinilodaGniaoc7uie99diBucuUmiape
bddmuissatoPRboltrScRrF28ne8iolBurMpm
SaoE46muinbuD4rloPNSAe63ee7fsnaiiuPou
NleumuiseaCPo7taro6Y9CFsdM7Rsut8llaCi
elNmuinamreG14SGP5b11mr01171ann2ul6Ar
oaKmuicnarFmuirhoBf14AdaeL8LHUa1heI6t
nPCu72ZnegordyH62C8Y5munahtnaLTTTTr4t
RaRadiummuiromreviL4ZincTdCmuimorhC6Y

SPOILER:

> The names, numbers, and symbols of each element is included. Some overlap completely.

Comment: I think the spoiler is a big give-away. With it I could find Phosphorus and Helium in a glance.

Comment: It's annoying that it says "Aluminum", when the official spelling (the one that isn't considered a "variant") is "Aluminium". Damn you Americans, you just can't stick with the standard used by the rest of the world, can you? (I've found 22 of them so far... not sure how it's going to get to 300, though).

Comment: Text format would be handy to copy and paste...

Comment: I believe I've found all bar 15 of them... but I'm having particular trouble, for some reason, with Zinc.

Comment: Yea, text format would solve that, be able to highlight the capital Z's and lowercase c's :)

Comment: @TimCouwelier ... but that kills all the fun.

Comment: So, it turned out that I had already found Zinc, and just hadn't noticed when figuring out which ones I was missing.

Comment: The letters are for the smaller image that has the correct spelling of Aluminium. In case someone want to solve it as a computer puzzle.

Comment: Mark N, they do match, just that it is transposed. The first two images however don't seem to match

Comment: @TimCouwelier I have fixed the letters.

Comment: @Bob - I really didn't need you to redo it with the corrected spelling. Anyone who has a passing knowledge of the periodic table should know that Americans spell Aluminium "Aluminum" and Sulphur "Sulfur" (although "Sulfur" is now the officially recognised main spelling for that element). But thanks for the consideration, anyway - I really just used it as an opportunity for a small rant.

Comment: @GlenO Which has your favourite colour: grey Aluminium or Sulpher? or should I say "favorite color: gray aluminum or Sulfur?" ;p

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have found the names, symbols, and atomic numbers for the first 118 elements in the periodic table. $118*3=354$ so I presume these are the "over 300" hidden things mentioned by OP.

I used the small grid with the plain text that I could copy. My search preferred to find items in the top left so, although there could be multiple instances of a symbol or number, the highest and furthest left option will be highlighted. To be fair, this could cause some confusion if, for instance, the same two cells are highlighted for both 17 and 71. However, I can assure you that you *will* find each answer highlighted.

---

### Element Names

> [image: Solved for Names]

### Element Symbols

> [image: Solved for Symbols]

### Element Atomic Numbers

> [image: Solved for Atomic Numbers]

---

On an unrelated note, only 242 of the 1,369 characters in the word search were left unused in my results. This gives a usage rate of about $82\%$. That could probably be increased by a more intelligent search that favored all characters being used instead of just the first one it finds. That's some tightly packed information.

Comment: If you're wondering why I said the *first* 118 elements on the table when there are only 118 elements on the table is because these are the only ones of which the news has come to Harvahd. There may be many others but they haven't been discovahd.

Comment: Good point. I think Tony Stark has [already created one](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Tony_Stark%27s_New_Element).

Answer (score 11):

I have found all of the

> Elements

Up to 118. I presume no more are present. Not sure where the "300" comes from, perhaps there's also something else hidden in the puzzle?

> [image: Here's the solution]

Note: colours are meaningless in my solution pic.

Comment: I am not sure if OP intended things such as O3 [Beside the 'n' in Germanium] to count (as ozone), since it is the short form of a compound? Or maybe M16 beside Titaniu'm' :p

Comment: If the OP accepts symbols too, there's for example "Pb" in the last column.

Comment: I also notice Unobtainium doesn't seem to be listed (yet there is kyrpton).. :(

Comment: @MarkN - Krypton is a real element - a noble gas, in fact.

Comment: @GlenO A bit of a long shot, but given leoll2's comment, what if the other 200 things are the symbols and the atomic weights? (I see Uuo nestled there between Gadolinium and Curium. Plus the atomic weights thing would explain why there's numbers)

Comment: @GlenO Unobtainium is real, we just can't obtain any yet ;p (sorry, I was thinking about kryptonite)

Comment: @leoll2 - the problem with that is that there would be a heap of repeats, which is usually not appropriate for word searches. For instance, I can spot quite a few "Ti" pairs and "Na" pairs, for instance.

Comment: @DennisMeng - I don't think it'll be symbols, and atomic weights are a little complicated... but I am noticing that 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, and 118 are all in there. I've also found 101, 103, 104, and 105... but I've found 104 twice, so it might not be meaningful.

Comment: Sorry 'bout getting your bounty. I see you're going to get a bigger one. I'll gave you +1 and the badge. You're certainly the one that figured out what we needed to find.

Comment: @Bob - Thank you for the bounty (increased). I really do appreciate it.